# Passing a struct instance by reference to ParameterizedThreadStart

Tags: c#, struct, pass-by-reference

I want to start a thread and as a parameter pass an instance of a struct by reference. The `ref` keyword worked fine before using threads but I can't seem to use `ref` now.

This is how my code currently is:

```
Thread melodyThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(PlayMelody));
melodyThread.Start(melody1);

private void PlayMelody(object parameter)
{
    Melody melody = (Melody)parameter;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want to pass an instance of struct `Melody` (`melody1`) by reference. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Mutable structs are evil. 2. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I'm on the .NET Compact Framework for XNA 4.0.

Comment: Do you need to pass the struct by reference because you are changing it and you want the calling code to access the changed data?

Comment: Yes, I want to set a "played" property of the struct so that when I come to play another melody it will not be chosen.

Comment: Can you use `Task<T>` if you're using the Compact library?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of possibilities I can think of.

**Solution One: Using a wrapper class**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var melody = new Melody { Value = 1 };
            var wrapper = new MelodyWrapper { Melody = melody };

            Thread melodyThread = new Thread(() => PlayMelody(wrapper));

            melodyThread.Start();
            melodyThread.Join();

            Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Melody.Value);
        }

        private static void PlayMelody(MelodyWrapper wrapper)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Melody.Value);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            wrapper.Melody.Value = 2;
        }
    }

    public struct Melody
    {
        public int Value;
    }

    public class MelodyWrapper
    {
        public Melody Melody;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, without using a Lambda:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var melody = new Melody { Value = 1 };
            var wrapper = new MelodyWrapper { Melody = melody };

            Thread melodyThread = new Thread(PlayMelody);

            melodyThread.Start(wrapper);
            melodyThread.Join();

            Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Melody.Value);
        }

        private static void PlayMelody(object parameter)
        {
            MelodyWrapper wrapper = (MelodyWrapper)parameter;
            Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Melody.Value);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            wrapper.Melody.Value = 2;
        }
    }

    public struct Melody
    {
        public int Value;
    }

    public class MelodyWrapper
    {
        public Melody Melody;
    }
}
```

**Solution two: Using a Delegate and returning the new value of Melody**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var melody = new Melody { Value = 1 };
            Func<Melody, Melody> play = PlayMelody;
            var result = play.BeginInvoke(melody, null, null);
            melody = play.EndInvoke(result);
            Console.WriteLine(melody.Value);
        }

        private static Melody PlayMelody(Melody melody)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(melody.Value);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            melody.Value = 2;
            return melody;
        }
    }

    public struct Melody
    {
        public int Value;
    }
}
```

I personally favour this second solution. Because it returns a new value, you could make `Melody` immutable if you used this solution.

(My preferred solution uses `Task<Melody>` but you can't use tasks.)

Comment: Very detailed answer and just what I need. Thanks. I went through with the second solution, it's more elegant.

Comment: An alternative to defining a wrapper class would be to use a `Melody[]` and always use element zero of it.  Personally, I think something like `public class ExposedValueWrapper<T> { public T Value;}` should be part of the Framework, so as to allow an object instance to be shared among code written by different people, but as yet no such thing exists.